# Disable reloading page angular 6 routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a problem with Angular. When I click to a link, browser reload site (Angular normally load only component which is connect with the path ). What I have to do?

Page1 and Page2 are default components.

app.module.ts:

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { Page1Component } from './page1/page1.component';
import { Page2Component } from './page2/page2.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component },
  { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Page1Component,
    Page2Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<a href="/page1">Page1</a>     
<a href="/page2">Page2</a>
```

Comment: I recommend your to read the docs https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea behind a single-page application is that the browser never triggers a request for another `.html` page, after fetching the initial `index.html`. 
Front-end navigation, enabled by Angular's `@angular/router` only imitates "pages".

When you open a new Angular "page", JavaScript is executed which deletes the currently visible elements from the DOM and replaces them with new ones, which form a different-looking screen -- which we call "page".

Using `href` on an anchor element (`<a>`), you're telling browser to fetch another page from the server. Instead, you should tell Angular to replace the DOM elements in order to form a new screen. You do this by using `routerLink` directive, which is available in `RouterModule`.

```
<a routerLink="/page1">Go to page 1</a>
```

I suggest reading through the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial available on [angular.io](https://angular.io), the official Angular website. It covers routing as well. Routing is also [covered here](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links).

Comment: I'm using `routerLink` but my components get reloaded anyway

Comment: @An-droid It's something else.

Answer (score 2):

Using `href` will perform URL redirection on that `anchor` tag, the redirection does happen on the same(since considered `target='_self' on anchor`).

Use `routerLink` directive provided by Angular Router API, which helps to navigate between the SPA pages.

```
<a routerLink="/page1">Page1</a>     
<a routerLink="/page2">Page2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`href` stands for hyper reference and is used for switching between multiple pages for a multipage application. As angular applications are mostly `SPA's (Single Page Applications)`, `routerLink` is an angular directive that loads the components within the page. Using `routerLink` only the components on the page are refreshed and not the page completely. Thus, you should use `routerLink` to prevent page refreshing. Following should be the content of your app.component.ts:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<a routerLink="/page1">Page1</a>     
<a routerLink="/page2">Page2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use routerlink as array for concatenating like `[routerLink]="['/page1', 'user']"`
More on this here https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink